# PHP regex expression for the following

Tags: regex, wordpress

```
<p>This will serve as a debug page.</p>
<p><img src="http://mattmueller.me/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/threadless.png" alt="Threadless" title="Threadless" width="650" height="150" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-73" /></p>

<p>This will serve as a debug page.</p>
<img src="http://mattmueller.me/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/threadless.png" alt="Threadless" title="Threadless" width="650" height="150" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-73" />
```

You'll notice that there is no `<p>` tags surrounding the image tag. I would like this just to remove `<p>` tags that wrap images. Wordpress is annoying.. essentially. If its easier with a `str_replace` or something, let me know. But I've tried. And failed so far....

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$x = preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>(<img[^>]*>)<\/p[^>]*>/', '$1', $x);
```

Where $x is your content

Answer (score 3):

Here's a great tool that will help you, hopefully:

http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @Matt- you're welcome.
 I didn't make it, I stumbled across it recently while trying to regex something in TextPad

Answer (score 2):

```
s/<p>(<img.*?\/>)<\/p>/$1/g
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So how would I use this with preg_replace?