# Regular expression to remove <p> tags around elements wrapped in [...]'s

Tags: regex, wordpress

I'm a total regexp noob. I'm working with wordpress and I'm desperately trying to deal with wordpress's wautop, which I hate and love (more hate!). Anyways I'm trying to remove `<p>` tags around certain commands.

Here's what I get:

```
<p>
[hide]
<img.../>
[/hide]
</p>
```

or

```
<p>
[imagelist]
<img .../>
<img .../>
[/imagelist]
</p>
```

Here's what I'd like:

```
[hide]
<img.../>
[/hide]
```

or

```
[imagelist]
<img .../>
<img .../>
[/imagelist]
```

I've tried:

```
preg_replace('/<p[^>]*>(\[[^>]*\])<\/p[^>]*>/', '$1', $content); // No luck!
```

**EDIT:
When I am doing the regexp it is still just a variable containing text.. It is not parsed as html yet. I know it is possible because I already did it with getting rid of p tags around an image tag. So I just need a regexp to handle text that will be parsed as html at some point in the future.
[Here's a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857490/php-regex-expression-for-the-following)**

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Comment: HTML is not "something a browser displays". It is an irregular markup language. "Irregular" means "regular expressions don't suffice".

Comment: What the hell difference does it make if it's just a variable containing text?  That text is NOT A REGULAR LANGUAGE.  It doesn't matter if it's in a variable, carved into stone, or spelled out on the sea bed by trained sponges, it's not regular and regex is the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
'%<p[^>]*>\s*(\[([^\[\]]+)\].*?\[/\2\])\s*</p>%s'
```

Explanation:

`\[([^\[\]]+)\]` matches the opening bbcode tag and captures the tag name in group #2.

`\[/\2\]` matches a corresponding losing tag.

`.*?` matches anything, reluctantly.  Thanks to the `s` flag at the end, it also matches newlines.  The effect of the reluctant `.*?` is that it stops matching the first time it finds a closing bbcode tag with the right name.  If tags are nested (within tags with the same name) or improperly balanced, it won't work correctly.  I wouldn't expect that be a problem, but I have no experience with WordPress, so YMMV.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use regular expressions to parse HTML, because HTML is, by definition, a non-regular language.  Period, end of discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I get what you are saying, though that's not what I meant. I edited it to clarify.

Comment: @Matt, just because it hasn't been put into <html> tags and displayed on a browser doesn't mean it isn't HTML and it isn't non-regular.  You might think you've handled your test cases, but trust me, somebody will throw up cases that your regexp will break on.

Answer (score 4):

The language of matching HTML tags is [context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language), not [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language).  This means regular expressions are probably not the right tool to use here.  Context-free languages require parsers rather than regular expressions.  So, you can either remove ALL `<p>` and `</p>` tags with a regular expression, or you can use an HTML parser to remove matching tags from certain parts of your document.

Comment: Its still text before its turned to html. see edited post please.